# PNPM and Visual Studio .Net 2019

Tags: visual-studio, pnpm

Has anyone been able to get PNPM (https://pnpm.io/motivation) working from within Visual Studio .Net?  NPM seems to be the default and I can't see how to change it.

Any guidance or steps or links would be very helpful.

Thanks